# eclipse content assist on generics not working anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

Eclipse used to autocomplete generics for me ... now it doesn't anymore and I can't figure out why.

I use to type

```
List<String> foo = new Arr
```

then hit Ctrl+Space and I would selecte ArrayList in the suggestions and the I would get

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

as a result.

But today eclipse is not total and I only get

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have absolutely no idea what I might have done ... and I cant figure out how to bring back this nice behavior I got so much used to  ...

Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857

Any help appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second construct (without generics in initialization) is new feature of Java7 called diamond operator. Eclipse is reflecting this and if you are using JDK7 in your project, it is used in auto-complete. If you try switch to back to JDK6, auto-complete would be using old construct.

More info:
[Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)
[Blog about diamond operator and Eclipse](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/java-7-diamond-operator.html)